# Add html/code in Magento HEADER

Tags: html, css, magento

I am new to magento, so i have little knowledge about it. I want to Add an Image or Html Code at the Header of Magento.I want this (http://prntscr.com/8c5ens) one to be placed here (http://prntscr.com/8c5eyy) .Can AnyOne guide me how to do it ?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=modify+magento+theme+header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the html template file.

One way to do that it's enable Template Path and Block Name hints:

1. Login to Magento Admin panel
2. Go to System->Configuration.
3. The Template Path and Block name will only appear for current website. So change the Current Configuration Scope to ‘Main Website’.
4. Go to the Advanced section and click on Developers.
5. Expand the Debug tab.
6. Set the Template Path Hints to ‘Yes’.
7. Set the Block Name Hints to ‘Yes’.
8. Click on ‘Save Configuration’ button.
9. Open Magento user panel and see the template path hints. It shows each file where the page element is located in.

Another way it's find the code in whole project (intuition needed):

1. Open developers tools of browser.
2. Find some specific pieces of code, copy it and try to find it through the whole project.

Probably it should be somewhere in app/design/frontend/ path.

Comment: i have found it. but its of php. and if i add html, its appearing below logo, can u provide me code how to make it appear at the middle ?

Comment: I need to see the source code. Try to use css property "float: left" for logo.